# What is the difference of bootstrapped standard error and lavaan default output standard error?

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I am doing `sem` with `lavaan` in R, and I found that even I don't input the bootstrap parameters, the output of `sem` will give me the standard error by default.

I am wondering what is the difference between the default output standard error and the bootstrapped standard error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type of estimator.  The default without `ordered=` outcomes is maximum likelihood, in which case the second derivative of the likelihood function (Hessian matrix) is used to obtain the *SE*s analytically.  There are different flavors depending on (in)complete data, or robust corrections for nonnormality.  This recent paper provides and nice overview of the options:

https://doi.org/10.1080/10705511.2021.1877548

A bootstrap *SE* is simply the *SD* of a statistic in the empirical bootstrap distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped a lot!